# How to fix/ set resolution on dell precision m4600 to 1600x900?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card

The top resolution is too high for me and wish to change to a resolution like 1600x900.
I've have a Dell Precision M4600 with NVIDIA Quardo 1000M,
with Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 on a  windows 7 64 bit.
The only resolution options I have are:-
1920x1080
1280x1024
1024x768
800x600
I have updated the graphics drivers from the dell website.
I also have an external monitor 1366x768.

How can I get resolution 1600x900 or close to for both internal and external monitors?

I have also installed NVIDIA drivers but still don't get any options

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd that you see resolutions with different aspect ratios (16:9, 5:4, 4:3), as if your monitor was not recognised at all.
Are graphic card and laptop display correctly identified in the settings? Are you changing the settings for the NVidia card or the Intel?

I would try installing the video drivers from the NVidia website rather than Dell and see if that makes any difference.

Also I recommend using the native resolutions of both monitors rather than forcing them to using the same, to avoid a drastic drop in the image quality.